# How to get information panel of a storyboard in XCode 6

Tags: xcode

I am new to XCode. I am using XCode for an ios development.

After following this tutorial, 
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/

I can't see the information panel for the main storyboard (the rightest panel) in the above screenshot.

And now my storyboard is poped out, how can it get it unpop out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go in menu "View -> Utilities -> Show utilities"